# Sendmail PHP Protocol and email header issue and SMTP issue with CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, email, smtp, sendmail

I would like to have two answers here,

1. I'm using sendmail protocol for sending emails from server as smtp protocol fails to send email using my CodeIgniter 2.2 framework (same code works with other servers, and SMTP works with other software). When the server guys checked the SMTP with CI3, it worked without issues.
2. When I use sendmail its showing the ssh user info in the email header as `Received: (from ssh-myuser@localhost)`

**SMTP Configuration**

```
$config = [
            'mailtype'  => 'html',
            'protocol'  => 'smtp',
            'wordwrap'  => true,
            'smtp_host' => 'smtp.example.com',
            'smtp_user' => 'info@example.com',
            'smtp_pass' => 'password',
            'smtp_port' => '587',
            'charset'   => 'iso-8859-1',
        ];
```

**SENDMAIL Configuration**

```
$config = [
            'mailtype'  => 'html',
            'protocol'  => 'sendmail',
            'mailpath'  => '/usr/sbin/sendmail',
            'wordwrap'  => true,
            'smtp_host' => 'smtp.example.com',
            'smtp_user' => 'info@example.com',
            'smtp_pass' => 'password',
            'smtp_port' => '587',
            'charset'   => 'iso-8859-1',
        ];
```

Please advise, where its wrong, and what needs to be done. Exposing ssh user account is not a good idea, I believe.